# Is it possible to define a TreeView hierarchical view template for a 'plain' collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, datatemplate

I have my model classes that look like this:

```
class Base 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Item : Base { ... }

class Group : Base 
{
    public List<Base> GroupItems { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, I have a view model with an `Items` collection, that I fill up like shown in the `FillUp()` method below:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Base> Items { get; set; }

    private void FillUp()
    {
        Item item1 = new Item { Name = "Item1" };
        Item item2 = new Item { Name = "Item2" };
        Group group = new Group { Name = "Group" };
        group.GroupItems.Add(item1);
        this.Items.Add(item1);
        this.Items.Add(item2);
        this.Items.Add(group);
    }
}
```

So, my `Items` collection now contains 2 objects of type `Item` and one object of type `Group`, which has a "parent-child" reference to one of the `Item` object.

What I want to achieve: I'd like to display this model in a `TreeView` so that all the `Item`s which belong to some `Group` should be displayed as child elements of that `Group`, despite of they are in the "root" collection.

It should then look like this:

```
- Item2
+ Group
   - Item1
```

I could use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to display parent-child elements, but this does not let me filtering out those items from the root collection that belong to some groups.

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type loc:Group}" ItemsSource = "{Binding GroupItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Item}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
  <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</TreeView>
```

With this view, I'm getting the `"Item1"` twice:

```
- Item1
- Item2
+ Group
    - Item1
```

Is there any way to get the desired result via view (XAML) markup only? Otherwise, I should change my view model so that the `Item`s will be only added into the `Group`s, not in the "root" collection (but that is what I try to avoid at the moment).

Comment: *Is there any way to do this via view (XAML) markup only?*... sure there is, but what's wrong with your current code... what error(s) are you getting.  At a quick glance, it seems that your XAML is ok.

Comment: With my current XAML, I'm getting no errors, I'm getting a wrong result (updated the question). My model representation appears in the `TreeView` twice, but I want it to appear only once as a child item.

Comment: *this does not let me filtering out those items from the root collection that belong to some groups*... that's not an error, that's the expected behaviour. If you don't want it to show the duplicate item, then don't add a duplicate item to the collection.

Comment: @Sheridan, I didn't say that this is an error, and I do know that this is the expected behavior. There are no duplicates in the collection by the way, as you can see in my code - it's just the view that displays the item twice. But I want to change only the view leaving my view model untouched (that means, I don't want to remove any items from the `Items` collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some indication of which Item belongs in a group , for this example iv'e added a Guid in Group and Item classes.

You can go about this in 2 ways :

1) Create a composite wrapper class .
   And create an ItemsSource of Wrapper class . Where there is a single item    which does not belong to a group , Children would just remain null.

```
public class Wrapper<T> where T : Base
{
    public List<T> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Base 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item : Base
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class Group : Base 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> GroupItems { get; private set; }
}
```

your second option is to use a CollectionView , and filter out Items which belong to a group.

```
private ICollectionView _baseView;
public ICollectionView BaseView
{

    get
    {
        if (_baseView == null)
        {
            _baseView = new ListCollectionView((IList) items);
            _baseView.Filter = o => o is Group || o is Item && (o as Item).GroupId != Guid.Empty;                   
        }
        return _baseView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but at the moment there's no indication in the `Item`s whether they have parents or not. I could filter my `Items`s by checking whether they belong to any group, but that might have performance issues assuming there would be thousands of `Item`s in the collection.

Comment: you can check against the instances them selves . 
check if an Item is not contained in any group. The indication was just an example . 

your other option like Sheridan suggested is just not to add them . 
but sometimes we like to keep the model collection flattened and un-touched for BL logic and some sort of View for UI-Logic

Answer (score 0):

You can define two Collections in your ViewModel one for all items and one for the tree, it seems to be simple.

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Base> AllItems { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Base> RootLevelItems { get; set; }
}
```

If you have only two levels (e.g. no nested groups) you can use ListView with GroupStyle.

Comment: That's a poor answer as there's no need to use two collections... how would the question author data bind them both to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property? -1

Comment: Thanks for downvote explanation. He shouldn't bind to both just to RootLevelItems. RootLevelItems collection models the tree structure.

Comment: A `CollectionViewSource` with `GroupDescriptions` is a good idea, thanks, but, as you can see in my code, nested groups are possible. Having a second collection could be a solution, but that's the view model. I'm wondering whether I can achieve my result by view only.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> There are no duplicates in the collection by the way, as you can see in my code - it's just the view that displays the item twice.

You said that there are no duplicates in your code, but clearly there is:

```
private void FillUp()
{
    Item item1 = new Item { Name = "Item1" };
    Item item2 = new Item { Name = "Item2" };
    Group group = new Group { Name = "Group" };
    group.GroupItems.Add(item1);  // Adding item1 into collection in Group 
    this.Items.Add(item1);  // Adding item1 into collection again
    this.Items.Add(item2);
    this.Items.Add(group);
}
```

Therefore, as I said, *this is the expected behaviour* and the `TreeView` is only showing you what you told it to. So to remove the duplicate item, simply don't add it to your collection:

```
private void FillUp()
{
    Item item1 = new Item { Name = "Item1" };
    Item item2 = new Item { Name = "Item2" };
    Group group = new Group { Name = "Group" };
    group.GroupItems.Add(item1);  // Adding item1 into collection in Group 
    // this.Items.Add(item1);  // Don't add item1 into collection again
    this.Items.Add(item2);
    this.Items.Add(group);
}
```

Comment: Again, this is not a duplicate. There is only one object of type `Item` (`item1`), it is just contained in the "master" `Items` collection and, additionally, in the `GroupItems` collection of another item. Both are necessary and cannot be avoided: I need the `item1` in the root `Items` collection by design, and the `group` object needs to know its children. So my original question was: how to achieve the desired view without changing my model (so, without removing anything from any collections).