# MVVM from List in Model to Hierarchy List in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a model that contains a flat list with person objects containing a parent ID. This list is not ordered, so children could come before their parent.

```
class PersonModel
{
  int ID;
  int Parent;
  string Name;
}
```

I want to display this in a Treeview and therefore in the VM I need to define the Children & Parent as a reference to other VM's. SO I have setup my PersonViewModel like so;

```
class PersonVM
{
  readonly PersonModel = _Person;
  PersonVM Parent;
  List<PersonVM> Children;

  public Name {
    get { return Person.Name; }
  }

  public PersonVM(PersonModel Person)
  {
    _Person = Person;
  }
}
```

In my TreeView VM I have a constructor that creates PersonVM's from a list of PersonModels;

```
class TreeViewVM
{
  public List<PersonVM> PersonList;

  TreeViewVM(List<PersonModel> Persons)
  {
    foreach (PersonModel Person in Persons)
    {
      PersonList.Add(new PersonVM(Person ));
    }
  }
}
```

I am now struggling to figure out the proper way of creating the heirarchy between the PersonVM's. I cannot access the Model from my Main VM, and in my thinking it should be like that. However that is where the ID is stored.

So what is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: ViewModel should prepare data for View. Model has list, but View required hierarchical data (for `TreeView`). Perfect job for the ViewModel. Taking your example ViewModel should create property `ObservableCollection<PersonVM>`, fill it and then you simply bind `TreeView.ItemsSource` to it. As for `PersonModel` instance it can be stored in `PersonVM` for later use by ViewModel.

Comment: You could take a look on [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340249/is-it-possible-to-define-a-treeview-hierarchical-view-template-for-a-plain-col).